# Как сделать правильный pull?

Tags: git, github

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Делаю изменения в локальном репозитории, потом делаю `git commit`. Проверяю git status - пишет "`master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged`". Но все файлы заккомитились нормально.

Хочу подтянуть изменения с сервера, делаю `git pull`. Снова проверяю `git status` и вижу что появились файлы в секции "`changed but not updated`” причем git советует "(`use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)`". Делаю `add`, файлики перешли в секцию '`will be committed`', делаю коммит, только теперь они исчезают из списков.

Почему приходиться повторно делать коммит после каждого пулла?
 have diverged`

Comment: Возможно, кто то успел обновить файлы на сервере. Соответственно, когда Вы делаете pull, происходит merge. А мердж требует коммита.

Уточнение - когда Вы делаете коммит перед pull, то Вы добавляете нужные файлыv (`git add`)? (или коммитите так `git commit -a`).

Comment: Я делаю git add, и добавляю все файлы которые были изменены, чтобы они переместились в секцию "will be committed".
Тоесть кто то сделал коммит, зупушил на сервер, а я делаю пулл и снова должен коммитить те же самые изменения что сделал другой человек?

Comment: Вы должны смерждить  (то есть слить вместе) свои изменения и его. Автоматически это сделать очень сложно (порой). И вот только измененные файлы и нужно коммитить.

Но если у Вас это происходит постоянно, то возможно, нужно поговорить с коллегами и разделить работу более аккуратно.

Но я рекомендую посмотреть, что там поменялось. Возможно, это переводы строк (то есть, в репозитории используются linux разделители, а у Вас виндовые).

Comment: Обычно для избежания таких ситуаций делают `git pull --rebase`, это сливает текущую версию и вместо мерджа переносит все локальные коммиты на верхушку ветки, тем самым необходимость мерджа пропадает вообще.

Comment: KoVadim, они работают с одной частью (папкой), я с другой. У нас конфликтов не должно быть. 
Я так понял, не нужно коммитить те изменения, которые добавили они, а я перенес пулом?

Comment: раз у Вас нет конфликтов по рабочему процессу, тогда смотрите, что поменялось. Я думаю, что это переводы строк. Но без знания, что там поменялось, мне сложно "угадать".

Answer (score 2):

Когда Вы делаете pull, происходит auto-merge Ваших данных с данными сервера. Если все проходит удачно, то комита Вам делать не требуется. Если возникает конфликты во время мерджа, то git сообщает Вам в каких файлах произошли конфликты и все изменения которые пришли с сервера остаются как изменения Вашей локальной версии. т.е. git просит Вас самому разрешить все конфликты вручную, проверить все изменения которые пришли сервера и сделать commit.
Если у Вас windows, то я рекомендую установить Tortoisegit (https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/). Это конечно зависит от личных предпочтений, но я лично совершенно ни чего не вижу в консоле что происходит с git. Tortoisegit делает все намного нагляднее, сразу видно где конфликты, какие изменения произошли с репозитарием.

Comment: какова ценность Вашего ответа? На вопрос ТС Вы не ответили.